# My website has hacked content like urls www.example.com/g1324,www.example.com/c1 are displaying while search using site:example.com in google?

Tags: php, search

Few days back i received a message that my website has contain malware from third party content ,after that i changed password for my server and remove hacked content from the server of my website, but in google search with using site:example.com it is showing so many unknown urls like example.com/g7465 example.com/c11 etc and also porn content is displaying, now how can i permanently remove these url and make my website keep safe, the urls should not appear in any google search with my website.

Comment: Make a new sitemap of your website and submit it through web master tools. Google will reindex your website within 24 hours. Changes on google search may take upto 48 hours for invalid search results to disappear.

Comment: btw look for what made your site vulnerable and fix that. otherwise it will get hacked again. I suppose your have some comment or feedback like system in your website, or some facebook like wall post etc. Thats 1 thing that helps hackers.

Comment: my website is www.colorssoftware.com  but my design everything is ok but  urls are coming and coming again and agian

Comment: @GowrisankarVeluturla — It is unclear what your question is. Are you asking how to make sure that search engines reindex your site so they'll remove links to deleted content or are you complaining that you haven't managed to remove the content?

Comment: some links are generating  like example.com/cg434 which are not we created ,while searching in google with site:example.com these spammy links are coming in google search i want to remove all these spammy links and they won't reappear ini my next searches